# Powershell Get-Variable doesn't retreive the Value but manually writing the Variable does

Tags: powershell

I am trying to Dynamically Create Sub Variables and assign them values, but since they are dynamically named, they need to be dynamically called and when using the get-variable command I cannot get it to actually show anything....

```
Function Get-LocalGroups {
    param(
        [String]$ComputerName
    )
    Remove-Variable -Scope Script -Name System.LocalGroups.* -Force
    $computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$ComputerName"
    $computer.psbase.children | where { $_.psbase.schemaClassName -eq 'group' } | foreach {
        $Members = $_.psbase.Invoke("Members") | foreach { ($_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null))}
        New-Variable -Scope Script -Name System.LocalGroups.$(($_.name).Replace(" ","-")) -Force
        $Script:System.LocalGroups.($_.name.Replace(" ","-")) = $Members
        $Members
    }

}

$System = @{}
$System.ComputerName = $Env:ComputerName
$System.LocalGroups = @{}

Get-LocalGroups -ComputerName $System.ComputerName

Get-Variable System.LocalGroups.* |ft -AutoSize
$System.LocalGroups.Users
```

Comment: `$_.name.replace` without parentheses?

Comment: I'm not sure how that relates to my question. When i get the get-variable it shows blank value for the variable but when i manually type out "$System.LocalGroups.Users" it shows a value for the variable.

Comment: `$System.LocalGroups.Users` and `${System.LocalGroups.Users}` are two different things.

Comment: Am I using ${System.LocalGroups.Users}?

Comment: @user1451070 No, you are not using `${System.LocalGroups.Users}`. But that is correct syntax to refer to variable with name `System.LocalGroups.Users`.

Comment: I am so angry right now... I spent way to many HOURS trying to figure this out... How does one dynamicly create a subvariable of $system.localgroups.

Comment: I am not sure, what are you calling by *subvariable*. You actually create some variables with `New-Variable` cmdlet, but you not set any value to them. You can use `-Value` parameter to do that. BTW, if you want to notify someone of your comment, then you should mention her/him/it: @user1451070

Comment: @user1451070 By writing _subvariablae_, do you eventually mean fields?

Answer (score 0):

*(I found this old unanswered question when searching for information on `Get-Variable`)*

## Variable names which include dots

You are creating variables with dots in the name:

> New-Variable -Scope Script -Name
> System.LocalGroups.$(($_.name).Replace(" ","-")) -Force

Normally dots would be used for *properties* of that variable/object, rather than creating a heirarchical namespace with the variable names.

If you want to use dots in your variable names, use curly brackets when you reference those variables as per the comments to the OP, for example:

```
${System.LocalGroups.Users}
```

This is explained a *little* more in the answers to a question I asked a few years ago: [Do curly braces mean anything in PowerShell variable declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36773800/do-curly-braces-mean-anything-in-powershell-variable-declaration)

## Alternative ideas

Instead of creating variables with `New-Variable` you could use a collection like a hashtable:

```
$LocalGroups = @{}
... | foreach {
        ...
        $LocalGroups.[($_.name) -replace(" ","-")] = $Members
    }

$LocalGroups.Users
```

Or you could contstruct a `PSCustomObject`. I won't try to reproduce the instructions here as there are plenty of examples of how to do this already.